# does javascript have block level scoping?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in java script. When I run this code an I face an error saying that div.parentNode is null. If make the 2 variables main and div as global variables then the code works perfectly fine. Why is it so?

```
var i = 0;

var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener('click',myFunction,false);

function myFunction () {

    if ( i < 1 ) {

        var main = document.getElementById("main");
        var div = document.createElement("div");    

        main.appendChild(div);
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        div.appendChild(para);
        div.setAttribute("id","newdiv");
        para.innerHTML = "This is a new div that has been created using java script.This is a new div that has been created using java script.This is a new div that has been created using java script.This is a new div that has been created using java script.This is a new div that has been created using java script.";

        i++
    }
    else {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        i=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On the first run of `myFunction`, i.e. the first click of the button, variable `i` has value `0` and so the `if` statement executes the first alternative.

On the second run, `i` has value `1` since the previous call executed `i++;`. Therefore, the second alternative of the `if` statement is run (the `else` part).

Since the `main` and `div` variables are **defined** only in the first alternative which has not executed, `div` is undefined on that second run.

The solution is to define `div` in the `else` block too:

```
function myFunction () {

    var div;

    if ( i < 1 ) {

        var main = document.getElementById("main");
        div = document.createElement('div');  

        main.appendChild(div);
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        div.appendChild(para);
        div.setAttribute("id","newdiv");
        para.innerHTML = "This is a new div that has been created using java script.This is a new div that has been created using java script.This is a new div that has been created using java script.This is a new div that has been created using java script.This is a new div that has been created using java script.";

        i++;
    } else {
        // get the div we created before
        div = document.getElementById('newdiv');
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        i=0;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you want to find `div` by id, not selector. There may be other `div` under `#main`, and queryBySelector returns the first it finds.

Comment: @jalynn2 True, I hadn't even noticed that an `id` attribute was set on the `div`, thanks!